# Change has_secure_token minimum length in Rails 6.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

Rails 6.1 introduces a setting for the length of a secure token, e.g.

```
has_secure_token :auth_token, length: 36
```

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SecureToken/ClassMethods.html

There's a `MINIMUM_TOKEN_LENGTH = 24` set here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/secure_token.rb

How do I go about overriding this? I need to have tokens with a shorter length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to overriding this ....

Create a file in `config/initializers/active_record/secure_token.rb`

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

module ActiveRecord
  module SecureToken
    MINIMUM_TOKEN_LENGTH = 2 // Add your minimum length
  end
end
```

Note: `has_secure_token` is using
**SecureRandom::base58** to generate minimum 24-character unique token, so collisions are highly unlikely.

Hope this patch will work for you.